# Add the word TOTAL to last row of Gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a dynamically created GridView and I used the sql code `WITH ROLLUP` to display the totals of the columns. But is it possible to display the word totals in the blank cell?

[image]

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
                                id="gvResults" 
                                CssClass="tblResults" 
                                onrowcreated= "gvResults_RowCreated"
                                AllowSorting="true" 
                                OnSortCommand="gvResults_Sort" 
                                DataKeyField="ID" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                                Visible =" true">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />

                        </asp:GridView>
```

SQL code to display GridView:

```
select

    c.Name,
    COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
    sum(case when (select count(jbs.status) from jobstat jbs where jbs.jobid=jn.id and jbs.Status=''DEL'')>0 then 1 else 0 end) as EPOD,
     sum(case when (select count(jbs.status) from jobstat jbs where jbs.jobid=jn.id and jbs.Status=''POD'')>0 then 1 else 0 end) as POD,
    SUM((select COUNT(ID) from job_debriefs WHERE JobID = jn.ID)) as Debriefs,
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON jn.JobOwnerID = c.ID
    LEFT JOIN manifestdetails md ON md.JobID = jn.ID and md.ColDelReturn = ''C''
    LEFT JOIN manifest man ON md.ManifestID = man.ID
    WHERE jn.IsActive = 1 AND c.Company_ID = 12
    GROUP BY c.Name WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING` SQL function to determine, whether `c.Name` is being *rolled up* in particular row:

```
select
ifnull(c.Name,'TOTAL') as Name,
COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
sum(case when (select count(jbs.status) from jobstat jbs where jbs.jobid=jn.id and jbs.Status=''DEL'')>0 then 1 else 0 end) as EPOD,
 sum(case when (select count(jbs.status) from jobstat jbs where jbs.jobid=jn.id and jbs.Status=''POD'')>0 then 1 else 0 end) as POD,
SUM((select COUNT(ID) from job_debriefs WHERE JobID = jn.ID)) as Debriefs,
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON jn.JobOwnerID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN manifestdetails md ON md.JobID = jn.ID and md.ColDelReturn = ''C''
LEFT JOIN manifest man ON md.ManifestID = man.ID
WHERE jn.IsActive = 1 AND c.Company_ID = 12
GROUP BY c.Name WITH ROLLUP
```

Remain aware, however, that if NULL value is allowed in original `c.Name` column, then this value will also be converted to word "TOTAL". There is no workaround for this in MySQL as far as I am aware (except for eliminating NULL values of course).

Comment: I get the error FUNCTION pxp.GROUPING does not exist. pxp is the name of the database

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly assumed MSSQL here. :) Updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer [to this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/adding-values-in-column-and-sum-of-the-column-values-in-grid/). It may helpful for you.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    Label Salary = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSalary");        
    m = m + int.Parse(Salary.Text);
    //Table tb = new Table();
  }

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
  {
    Label lblTotalPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Salary");
    lblTotalPrice.Text = m.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Sure. Thank You.